# comparing dates in c# taking null value into account

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I am comparing two dates where one is entered by user and the other one is sytem date time. i have the code working as it stands where the obstacle has occured is how to cater for null values. the basic code I have is:

```
if (mydate.ToShortDateString() != TodaysDate.ToShortDateString())

{
//Error Messaage
}

else
{
//do some code
}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated

Comment: It's not possible for a DateTime to be null is it? DateTimes are value types. Also you can compare DateTime objects directly ie `if (mydate == TodaysDate)`

Comment: @Phil DateTime cannot be null, but DateTime? can be - nullable types.  Also comparing DateTimes against each other takes into account the full date and time, not necessarily just the date as was elluded to in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you converting them to strings? Why not just compare the date portions of them as in `date1.Date != date2.Date`.

Comment: I wondered that. Maybe to only compare the date part of the DateTime?

Comment: @Phil: I assume so, but that's what the `Date` property is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare mydate as `DateTime?`, then it can hold null values.

As to how to handle the error, it depends on whether having a null value for mydate is considered an error or not. If it's an error, you could do:

```
if (mydate == null || mydate.ToShortDateString() != TodaysDate.ToShortDateString()) {
    // error
}
```

If it's not an error condition, you could do:

```
if (mydate != null && mydate.ToShortDateString() != TodaysDate.ToShortDateString()) {
    // error
}
```

If you don't declare mydate as `DateTime?` but instead just declare it as `DateTime`, then you can check for `DateTime.MinValue`, like this (`DateTime.MinValue` is the default value for a `DateTime` variable):

```
if (mydate == DateTime.MinValue || mydate.ToShortDateString() != TodaysDate.ToShortDateString()) {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ?? operator:

```
if ((mydate??DateTime.MinValue).ToShortDateString() != TodaysDate.ToShortDateString())
{
//Error Messaage
}

else
{
//do some code
}
```